# Why is emulator in Android Studio giving the wrong path? C:\buildbot\src\android

Tags: android-studio, emulation

When I start my Android Emulator for flutter, it continuously gives the following error.

```
Emulator: C:\buildbot\src\android\emu-master-dev\external\qemu\android\android-emugl\host\libs\Translator\GLES_V2/GLESv30Imp.cpp:glWaitSync:560 error 0x501
```

whereas I'm unable to locate this path on my system. I'm running Android Studio on Windows 10 Pro.

My original android location is as follows.

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded Android Studio to latest version and that fixed it.